# Getting hidden input using next and parent in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a problems retriving values from two input boxes, using the parent(). and next() functions. . In my head this should work! can anyone see what i'm missing?

Thanks.

I have this **HTML**

```
<tr>
<td class='headline2' style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top:20px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left;"><?= $value['f_name'] . " " . $value['l_name']; </td>
<td class='headline2'><?= $value[0]->end ?><br><?= $value[0]->start ?></td>
<td class='headline2'style='padding-right:18px;'><?= $value[0]->updated ?></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->studentApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->companyApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input class="approveME" value="<?= $value[0]->application_id ?>"   <? if ($value[0]->koordinatorApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  id="<?= $i ?>" type="checkbox"><label for="<?= $i ?>" ><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><input class="deleteME "type="image" src="../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/images/DELETE.png"><td>
</tr> 
<input class="hidden" value="<?= $value[1] ?>">
<input class="hidden" value="<?= $value[0]->user_id ?>">
```

And this **JQUERY**

```
 $('.content').on('click', '.deleteME', function() {
    var class_id = $(this).parent().parent().next().val();
    var user_id = $(this).parent().parent().next().next().val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: (my_ajax_script.ajaxurl),
        data: ({action: 'delete_student_from_class', class_id: class_id, student_id: user_id}),
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("data something" + msg);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: you can directly give id's to hidden inputs and can get those values rather than lengthy script

Comment: where is the $('.content') element placed? i guess you're getting a wrong referencing using $(this)...

Comment: Where is your `<table>` tag? You would need a `parent()` for it also.

Comment: SRy, I couldt use ID's, because the table is made several times with different data. Using ID's caused all the button's to delete the same user. Thx for the quick response all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have html elements in table directly rather you need to put them in some td. The html should be changed. You can add hidden field in the same row in new td after your .deleteME.

Html

```
tr>
<td class='headline2' style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top:20px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left;"><?= $value['f_name'] . " " . $value['l_name']; </td>
<td class='headline2'><?= $value[0]->end ?><br><?= $value[0]->start ?></td>
<td class='headline2'style='padding-right:18px;'><?= $value[0]->updated ?></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->studentApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->companyApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input class="approveME" value="<?= $value[0]->application_id ?>"   <? if ($value[0]->koordinatorApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  id="<?= $i ?>" type="checkbox"><label for="<?= $i ?>" ><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><input class="deleteME "type="image" src="../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/images/DELETE.png"><td>
<td>
<input class="hidden" value="<?= $value[1] ?>">
<input class="hidden" value="<?= $value[0]->user_id ?>">
</td>
</tr>
```

*Javascript*

```
var class_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidden:eq(0)').val();
var user_id =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidden:eq(1)').val();
```

Or

```
var class_id = $(this).parent().next('td').find('.hidden:eq(0)').val();
var user_id =  $(this).parent().next('td').find('.hidden:eq(1)').val();
```

Comment: This worked for me, when using the .closest('tr') apporach, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` can get confusing and when your DOM changes it will break your code.

Maybe you could try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
<td class='headline2' style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top:20px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left;"><?= $value['f_name'] . " " . $value['l_name']; </td>
<td class='headline2'><?= $value[0]->end ?><br><?= $value[0]->start ?></td>
<td class='headline2'style='padding-right:18px;'><?= $value[0]->updated ?></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->studentApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if ($value[0]->companyApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  type="checkbox"><label><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><div class="approve"><input class="approveME" value="<?= $value[0]->application_id ?>"   <? if ($value[0]->koordinatorApproved == 1) { ?>checked<? } ?>  id="<?= $i ?>" type="checkbox"><label for="<?= $i ?>" ><span></span></label></div></td>
<td><input class="deleteME data-class="<?= $value[1] ?>" data-user="<?= $value[0]->user_id ?>" "type="image" src="../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/images/DELETE.png"><td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$('.content').on('click', '.deleteME', function() {
    var class_id = $(this).data('class');
    var user_id = $(this).data('user');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: (my_ajax_script.ajaxurl),
        data: ({action: 'delete_student_from_class', class_id: class_id, student_id: user_id}),
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("data something" + msg);
        }

    });
});
```

Reference: [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.